# Find nearest value to zero with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to automatically find the nearest value to zero with gnuplot of a column. I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
stats 'file.dat' u abs($1)
```

and then I should have the nearest value to zero by taking STATS_min

```
-0.018492   -0.00369832
-0.0106795  -0.00352183
-0.00612481 -0.0016998
-0.00221856 -0.00160066
0.00168769  -0.00148317
0.00559394  -0.00135358
0.00950019  -0.00119879
0.0134064   -0.00102774
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did the following and mind the `()` around `abs($1)`:

```
stats $Data u (abs($1)) nooutput
print STATS_min
```

you would get: `0.00168769`, which would be correct for your current data.

*However*, be careful, if there was a value e.g. `-0.0001`, this would return `+0.0001`.

Hence you have to use "two" columns for `stats`, one for finding the minimal distance to zero and the other one for returning the value with the original sign.
So, on purpose, below I inserted a line `-0.0001   -0.99999`

**Script:**

```
### get nearest value to zero
reset session

$Data <<EOD
-0.018492   -0.00369832
-0.0106795  -0.00352183
-0.00612481 -0.0016998
-0.00221856 -0.00160066
-0.0001     -0.99999
0.00168769  -0.00148317
0.00559394  -0.00135358
0.00950019  -0.00119879
0.0134064   -0.00102774
EOD

stats $Data u 1:(abs($1)) nooutput

print STATS_pos_min_y
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
-0.0001
```

**Addition:**

Here is an alternative suggestion without `stats`. In case you want to label the extracted point, you can extract the coordinates during the plot command, i.e. you go through the data only once.

**Script:**

```
### get nearest value to zero
reset session

$Data <<EOD
-0.018492   -0.00369832
-0.0106795  -0.00352183
-0.00612481 -0.0016998
-0.00221856 -0.00160066
-0.0001     -0.0015
0.00168769  -0.00148317
0.00559394  -0.00135358
0.00950019  -0.00119879
0.0134064   -0.00102774
EOD

set key noautotitle
set yzeroaxis

plot x0=y0=NaN $Data u (x0!=x0?x0=$1:abs($1)<abs(x0)?(y0=$2,x0=$1):$1):2 w p pt 7 lc "red", \
     '+' u (x0):(y0):(sprintf("(%g,%g)",x0,y0)) every ::::0 w labels offset 0,-1 left
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]